# Design patterns to manage multiple windows/screens?

Tags: design-patterns, management, windows

Supposed there is an application with multiple windows, like:

Logo splashscreen
Connecting... screen
Login-usercontrols screen
Logging in... screen
etc.

Is there a design pattern, which allows to effectively manage all those windows? (to hide previous windows, display a new window etc.)

Comment: Questions about a specific technology stack are better asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Ok, I will delete the SWT. The question is about a pattern.

Comment: As @thorstenmüller already mentioned, implementation questions are more suitable for Stack Overflow, [but you already posted the question there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777053/how-to-manage-multiple-splashscreens-in-swt-java). Please don't post exactly the same question on multiple sites, and give our [FAQ] a thorough read to see what questions we welcome on Programmers.

Comment: If you do update your question to be in accordance with our [FAQ], please flag it for moderation attention so we can review and re-open it.

Comment: I believe there are no patterns for this. It all heavily depends on GUI stack, OS and what exactly do you want your windows to do.

Comment: See my answer to your StackOverflow question.

Comment: If you make it a web app, most of this will be given to you by the browser or a MVC framework. .Net also has WPF with its page navigation. I don't know anything about SWT, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mediator** promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently.

As an example, consider the implementation of a dialog box to present a collection of widgets such as buttons, menus, and entry fields. There may be dependencies between the widgets in the dialog, e.g., selecting an entry in a list box might change the contents of an entry field.

Such dependencies can be reduced by encapsulating collective behavior *in a mediator* object. A mediator is responsible for *controlling and coordinating the interactions of these objects*. The mediator acts as an intermediary and keeps objects in the group from referring to each other explicitly. The objects only know the mediator, thus reducing the number of interconnections.